# Command Line Tool - Error - xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: command-line, installation, swift3, gzip, carthage

I am getting this error while building the `SwiftJSON` framework to the Some Xcode project through Carthage Dependency Manager.

> Sivaramaiahs-Mac-mini:GZipDemoApp vsoftMacmini5$ carthage update
>   --platform iOS
>
> *** Fetching GzipSwift
>
> *** Fetching SwiftyJSON
>
> *** Checking out GzipSwift at "3.1.1"
>
> *** Downloading SwiftyJSON.framework binary at "3.1.3"
>
> *** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/7m/y0r2mdhn0f16zz1nlt34ypzr0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.apLXCc.log
>
> A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project
>   /Users/vsoftMacmini5/Desktop/GZipDemoApp/Carthage/Checkouts/GzipSwift/Gzip.xcodeproj
>   CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES -list)
>   failed with exit code 72:
>
> xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer
>   tool or in PATH

Answer (score 887):

I solved that problem by setting the Command Line Tools in Xcode. Go to:

> Xcode > Preferences > Locations

And select the command line tool from the dropdown. If you have only one version of Xcode installed, there should be only one option. If you have several versions of Xcode, then you must choose the one you need.

**Update (added image for reference)**

[image]

Comment: It didnt even have anything set by default for me when I looked at that setting until I set it to xCode X

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why it was unselected, maybe after install carthage, and selecting my version like in the image.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I wonder if it's an issue with people on brand new machines.

Comment: Had to do this for 10.3 on Catalina.

Comment: Thank you, 
my setup : Catalina 10.15.7 with Xcode 10.1

Answer (score 111):

## The simplest fix is from CLI:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

*(this should be path to your Xcode.app)*

By the way this can happen even if you have only one version of Xcode . It happens when you instal `homebrew` before the first Xcode installation (which makes sense because you may want to install Xcode through `mas install 497799835` and `mas` needs `homebrew`).

Comment: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer; sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This should be the selected answer. This is correct and tells you why it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Following command worked for me

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).