# Compilation error after upgrade to macOS Mojave | fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c, macos, cython, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading my mac OS from macOS High Sierra to macOS Mojave (Version 10.14), I am encountering an error in running a script (which I was able to run perfectly properly before upgradation.)  Presently, I am running python 2.7.15 with conda as environment manager, and have gcc 5.3.0 installed all within macOS 10.14 Mojave.

This is the software (Cython) that I was running ( `https://github.com/sidd0529/COSMOS_Lens`)

The package used to run just fine when I was running it before ( using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`). But, when I run it now, I encounter the following error:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c cosmos_cy.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/cosmos_cy.o -O3
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.3.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
             from /anaconda2/include/python2.7/Python.h:19,
             from cosmos_cy.c:4:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I implemented the suggestions given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877659/fatal-error-limits-h-no-such-file-or-directory) ( `xcode-select --install`) , but that doesn't work. I uninstalled Anaconda in my computer and reinstalled it again, but that also didn't solve the problem.

I will be really thankful if someone can tell me what I should do to be able run this package properly again.

Comment: It's late here, and this is a shot in the dark, but open XCode and make sure you've accepted the license agreement.  Then follow that link you posted.  Also, check [XCode-Preferences->Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743713/command-line-tool-error-xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-xcodebuild-n/41536029#41536029)

Comment: James: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the method that you suggested; sadly it didn't work.

Comment: @Commoner did you ever find a solution for this?