# Carthage update fail with exit code 1 when upgrade MacOs and Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

After upgrade your OS and/or your Xcode.

When you run

```
$ carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

you would get an output like:

> Fetching FooLibrary
>
> A shell task (/usr/bin/env git fetch --prune --quiet https://github.com/foodeveloper/FooLibrary.git refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* (launched in /Users/yourUser/Library/Caches/foo.package/dependencies/FooLibrary)) failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 7):

This issue happen with Carthage 0.33.0 and Xcode 11.

To solve this issue:

First: Open your new Xcode and select the last CLI to make sure that you are using the last CLI.

[Command Line Tool - Error - xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743713/command-line-tool-error-xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-xcodebuild-n)

Second:  Please You could fix it by deleting the cache of Carthage:
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
source: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/340

Comment: The "Second" tip helped me a lot. I had the same issue that OP reported, with RxSwift.

Comment: Second tip helped me too.  Thanks!