# Unable to find utility actool: not a developer tool or in PATH - Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

I am getting an error while running the `Build and Run` command on macOS Monterey with Unity 2021.3.

The error is: `Unable to find utility actool: not a developer tool or in PATH`

Any fix for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already resolve in this question [Command Line Tool - Error - xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743713/command-line-tool-error-xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-xcodebuild-n) ,

These are the steps in order to resolve the issue:

- Open XCode
- Preferences > Location
- Command Line Tool: `XCode <version>`